# Unable to process Ajax/jQuery request in Django back end

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views

Below is my Django code to process Ajax/jQuery request. Django filter method with 'q' parameter is not working. Could this be because Ajax request is in JSON format.  Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong ?

Views.py

```
def get_names(request):
   q = request.GET.get('term', '')
   names = Names.objects.filter(names__startswith=q)[:10]
   results = []
   if names.count > 0:
      for name in names:
        name_json = {}
        name_json['id'] = name.id
        name_json['label'] = name.name
        name_json['value'] = name.name
        results.append(name_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
   else:
         data = 'fail'

   mimetype = 'application/json'
   return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

Below is my jQuery code

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
$( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
        $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.ajax({
            url: "/get_names/",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {
                term: $input.val()
            }
        })
        .then( function ( response ) {
            $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
        });
    }
});});
```

Comment: why `crossDomain: true,`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), dataType affects the response, not the request, so that shouldn't be your problem. Try adding `print request.GET` at the start of your view - this should tell you whether the term parameter is actually being sent through. My only other thought is that your $input is losing its value at some point - possibly triggered by `$ul.listview( "refresh" );`? - you should probably change

```
data: {
    term: $input.val()
}
```

to

```
data: {
    term: value
}
```

since you've already retrieved the value further up.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I try and print request.GET , I get `<QueryDict: {u'q': [u'john']}>`. I am trying to assign the query in this case 'john' to 'q' in my django method so that I filter my database accordingly. Also, changing the term from `$input.val()` to `value` did not help.

Comment: It is strange that you send a `term` variable, but a `q` variable arrives at the server. So your django variable `q` will be the empty string.